# How to perform leverage browser caching in rails 4 and nginx?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, caching, nginx, browser

In my web application, I have a web page **https://www.dockettech.com/rental-agreement**.I need to perform leverage browser caching for this page.While running it through page speed, it throws the following instructions:

```
Leverage browser caching for the following cacheable resources:
https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js (20 minutes)
https://js-agent.newrelic.com/nr-971.min.js (60 minutes)
https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js (2 hours)
```

My web application is running on nginx server and hosted on amazon aws. I am novice developer.Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is telling you that those JavaScript files are served with headers that mark them as cacheable for only a short amount of time: if your visitor only came once a day  to the site for example, they would make a request for those assets each time. If the assets were served with a cache lifetime of a month then this would happen less often.

However, you're not serving the assets, so you can't change their cache expiry. It almost certainly doesn't matter. All those 3 are fairly widespread - even if your users don't visit your site that often, there's a very good chance they've visited a site using those libraries recently enough for them to come.